# Need to center a ul within a div ie6 & ie7

Tags: css, html, center, html-lists

I have a ul that i need to center within a div. The code i have (you'll find below) works in every browser apart from ie6 & ie7 where the content is floated left rather than centered. I've stripped out my code to the very basics. I have tried to work through numerous fixes for this without success as yet so any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

```
//CSS
#galleryThumbs {
    width:900px;
    height:125px;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0px auto;
}
ul.thumb {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    display:inline-block;
}
ul.thumb li {
    width:65px;
    height:65px;
    margin:0 2px 0 2px;
    border:1px solid #ffffff;
    display:inline-block;
    float:left;
}

//HTML
<div id="galleryThumbs">
    <ul class="thumb">
        <li><img src="http://www.thewoom.co.uk/clients/lowdklea/work/01_thumb1.jpg"></li>
        <li><img src="http://www.thewoom.co.uk/clients/lowdklea/work/01_thumb2.jpg"></li>
        <li><img src="http://www.thewoom.co.uk/clients/lowdklea/work/01_thumb3.jpg"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Many thanks in advance
Brendan

Comment: The worst bit is having to support IE6  :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

IE 6 and IE 7 do not support `display:inline-block`

You can override this with a IE CSS hack to the `inline-block` elements

```
zoom: 1;
*display: inline;
```

I would put those wrapped in IE conditional comments to target IE only.

Demo at http://www.jsfiddle.net/gaby/qArVS/2

Comment: Paniyar & Gaby, many thanks for such quick responses. Gaby, i've implemented your solution and this works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

IE6/7 doesn't support `display: inline-block` on elements which are by default `display: block`. See also [Quirksmode.org: CSS2 - The `display` declaration](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/display.html):

> IE 6/7 accepts the value only on elements with a natural `display: inline`.

The `<ul>` is by default `display: block`, so this ain't going to work.

One of the solutions is to give the `<ul>` a fixed width so that it can be centered to its parent by `margin: 0 auto`.

Answer (score 1):

The solution without hacks for internet explorer 7 is add to your code this:

```
    #yourdiv {
            width: 100%;
            position: relative;
            text-align: center;
    }

            #yourdiv ul {
                    float: left;
                    position: relative;
                    left: 50%
                    text-align: center;
            }

                    #yourdiv ul li {
                            float: left;
                            position: relative;
                            display: block;
                            right: 50%;                
                    }
```

With this you can center a unsorted list in Internet Explorer 7 without hacks.

Comment: This didn't work for me in IE9 compatibility mode w/ document mode set to IE7.

Answer (score 0):

The above (I mean the one with the width declaration for the UL) solution is the only one I came up to.
By the way, 2 things:

1- Your declaration for the Doctype is triggering quirks mode because the img tags are not xhtml-style properly closed.

2- Paniyar developed a new property for Float, CENTER. It doesn´t exist. Not in my books at least.

My two cents...

Comment: Thanks for having a look Billeeb. If you have a look at Gaby's jsfiddle link this is the accepted solution. I have tested this cross-browser including ie6 & ie7 and it works.